# No resource identifier found for attribute 'importantForAccessibility' in package 'android'

Tags: android

#### My Problem

I have a UI component, which I want to be ignored by accessibility. This can be done by adding `android:importantForAccessibility="no"` from API 16. My minSdkVersion is 15 and I can't change it for some reason. targetSdkVersion is set to"21". I put a version with importantForAccessibility attribute in layout-v16. I hope the app will choose this version on devices with Android version 16 or greater, and use the default version (without importantForAccessibility attribute) on devices running Android 15 or below. However, I can't compile with an error:

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'importantForAccessibility' in package 'android'
```

#### I have tried

If I use `importantForAccessibility="no"` instead of `android:importantForAccessibility="no"`, compiling will be fine but this component is not skipped by Accessibility service.

I also tried to add this attribute in Java code however, I can't compile as well.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
    layout.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
}
```

#### What I am using

To make it easy to understand, I am copying the xml file twice. The only difference is the importantForAccessibility attribute.

res/layout/my_layout.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ...
    android:layout_height="1dp">

</FrameLayout>
```

res/layout-v16/my_layout.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ...
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:importantForAccessibility="no">

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What is your target sdk version? is it set to 16?

Comment: targetSdkVersion is set to "21".